# compile error on building full aws-sdk-cpp for linux

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I use CMake 3.21.2 and got this error:

```
$ cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp-1.9.89 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...    
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Updating version info to 1.9.89
-- Custom memory management disabled
-- Performing Test CURL_HAS_H2
-- Performing Test CURL_HAS_H2 - Success
-- Performing Test CURL_HAS_TLS_PROXY
-- Performing Test CURL_HAS_TLS_PROXY - Success
CMake Error at aws-cpp-sdk-core/CMakeLists.txt:504 (aws_use_package):
  Unknown CMake command "aws_use_package".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ec2-user/sdk/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
$
```

I use the AWS steps and don't have any idea.
Must i configure something in CMakeFile.txt for this simple building?

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem was sloved by using *git clone --recursive* to get the SDK and it's dependencies, as it's shown in the instruction:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp
```